# submit и invoke в ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, concurrency

Подскажите наиболее просто и с примерами если можно разницу между submit и invoke в ForkJoinPool и когда их лучше всего использовать. Шот гугл не помогает найти эти ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invoke` - задача будет выполнена и будет возвращен результат задачи.

`execute` и `submit` возвращают задачу в очередь и может быть продолжена и в другом потоке. То есть не ждет завершения задачи

Если вы хотите видеть результат выполнения, то вызываете `join` после `execute` или `submit`